# Build mirroring on top of SQL2008R2 SQL cluster

Tags: cluster, sql-server-2008-r2, disaster-recovery, mirroring

On our SharePoint 2010 farm, we are using SQL 2008 R2. Currently, a SQL cluster (with 2 SQL server sitting at same data center) is built to provide auto-failover. However, it has no DR ability.

We are requested to provide DR ability to the system. One of approach we are considering is adding a new SQL server (the 3rd server) at DR site. Then setup mirroring with the SQL cluster. Is it possible for SQL 2008 R2?

I think not many systems is setup in this way. I fail to find any supporting document from Microsoft or from the Internet.

Answer (score 4):

This article explains the issue pretty well: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff658546(v=sql.100).aspx.

I am using Failover Clustering for most of my highly available DBs (both Oracle and MS SQL). In order to build a cluster you need either a separate SAN/NAS serving as a shared storage for your hosts or use some free 3rd-party mirroring solution like Starwind https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free. Obviously this scenario is rather SQL 2008 on top of mirroring but does the same job preventing downtime and data loss.

Comment: Sorry I am not SQL expert so the article is difficult to me. Do you mean that setup mirroring on a SQL cluster is possible?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP is asking if he can add a mirror when the source instance is already part of a failover cluster.

Comment: Failover Cluster is not equal to mirroring. The answer explains the mirroring part pretty well. The idea is that you do not mirror the SQL server/cluster itself but the complete storage behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. [This article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/database-mirroring-and-sql-server-failover-cluster-instances) outlines the scenarios and gives a sample topology.

> Typically, when mirroring is used with clustering, the principal
>   server and mirror server both reside on clusters, with the principal
>   server running on the failover clustered instance of one cluster and
>   the mirror server running on the failover clustered instance of a
>   different cluster. You can establish a mirroring session in which one
>   partner resides on the failover clustered instance of a cluster and
>   the other partner resides on a separate, unclustered computer,
>   however.
>
> If a cluster failover makes a principal server temporarily
>   unavailable, client connections are disconnected from the database.
>   After the cluster failover completes, clients can reconnect to the
>   principal server on the same cluster, or on a different cluster or an
>   unclustered computer, depending on the operating mode. Therefore, when
>   deciding how to configure database mirroring in a clustered
>   environment, the operating mode you use for mirroring is significant.